# Formatting negative values in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to get the correct negative value format displayed:

Right now it is showing (19%), when I want to show it as -19%.

I've got an XML file with

`<PerChg>-0.190</PerChg>`

Formatting it in XSL doesn't work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(PerChg, '#0%')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(PerChg, '#0%;-#0%')"/>
```

Even tried:

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="decimalChangePercent" minus-sign="-" />
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(PerChg, '#0%;-#0%', 'decimalChangePercent')"/>
```

Any ideas? Am in the .NET world, using XslCompiledTransform/XSLT 1.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Not seeing the problem...

**This input XML file,**

```
<PerChg>-0.190</PerChg>
```

**provided to this XSLT,**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(PerChg, '#0%')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**yields this output,**

```
-19%
```

**as expected.**

Answer (score 1):

Bingo, found the culprit!

There's a JavaScript function that converts all negative values into parentheses.

```
function MakeNegative() {
                TDs = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
                for (var i = 0; i < TDs.length; i++) {
                    var temp = TDs[i];
                    if (temp.firstChild && temp.firstChild.nodeValue) { // if not null
                        if (temp.firstChild.nodeValue.indexOf('-') == 0) {
                            temp.className += " negative";
                            temp.firstChild.nodeValue = '(' + temp.firstChild.nodeValue.replace('-', '') + ')';
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Thanks for your confirmation @kjhughes to make me look harder!